# Naming elements of a nested list from their index in R

Tags: r, list, nested

I got this nested list :

```
dico <- list(list(list(c("dim.", "dimension", "dimensions", "mesures"
), c("45 cm", "45", "45 CM", "0.45m")), list(c("tamano", "volumen", 
"dimension", "talla"), c("45 cm", "45", "0.45 M", "45 centimiento"
)), list(c("measures", "dimension", "measurement"), c("45 cm", 
"0.45 m", "100 inches", "100 pouces"))), list(list(c("poids", 
"poid", "poids net"), c("100 grammes", "100 gr", "100")), list(
    c("peso", "carga", "peso especifico"), c("100 gramos", "100g", 
    "100", "100 g")), list(c("weight", "net wieght", "weight (grammes)"
), c("100 grams", "100", "100 g"))), list(list(c("Batterie oui/non", 
"batterie", "présence batterie"), c("Oui", "batterie", "OUI"
)), list(c("bateria", "bateria si or no", "bateria disponible"
), c("si", "bateria furnindo", "1")), list(c("Battery available", 
"battery", "battery yes or no"), c("yes", "Y", "Battery given"
))))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "dim."       "dimension"  "dimensions" "mesures"   

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "45 cm" "45"    "45 CM" "0.45m"
```

What I want is to create a list with the same structure but instead of having the original values, I want to have a sort of "index" name like :

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[[1]][[1]][[1]]
[1] "1|1|1|1"       "1|1|1|2"  "1|1|1|3" "1|1|1|4"   

[[1]][[1]][[2]]
[1] "1|1|2|1" "1|1|2|2"    "1|1|2|3" "1|1|2|4"
```

and so forth ...

Of course the number of elements is not constant through the different nested indexes. Anyone know how to do that? I heard about rapply but I could not make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `melt` (from `reshape2`) to convert the nested `list` to a data.frame with the index columns ('L1', 'L2', 'L3') and the 'value' column, convert it to `data.table` (`setDT(...)`), grouped by 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', we get the sequence of rows (`1:.N`), `paste` the elements of the rows with `do.call` to a single `vector`, then `relist` it to a `list` with the same structure as that of 'dico' by specifying the `skeleton`.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
dico2 <- relist(do.call(paste, c(setDT(melt(dico))[, 1:.N ,
          by =  .(L1, L2, L3)], sep="|")), skeleton = dico)
dico2
#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[[1]][[1]][[1]]
#[1] "1|1|1|1" "1|1|1|2" "1|1|1|3" "1|1|1|4"

#[[1]][[1]][[2]]
#[1] "1|1|2|1" "1|1|2|2" "1|1|2|3" "1|1|2|4"

#...

#[[3]][[3]]
#[[3]][[3]][[1]]
#[1] "3|3|1|1" "3|3|1|2" "3|3|1|3"

#[[3]][[3]][[2]]
#[1] "3|3|2|1" "3|3|2|2" "3|3|2|3"
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this recursive function with a 2-line body.  It does not assume a fixed depth and allows unbalanced lists. No packages are used.

It accepts an object `L` and a level.  If the object is not a list then we have a leaf and it returns its levels.  If the object is a list then we have a node and it iterates over its components invoking `indexer` on each passing the concatenation of `lev`, `i` and `|` for the ith component's level.

```
indexer <- function(L, lev = character(0)) {
    if (!is.list(L)) paste0(lev, seq_along(L))
    else Map(indexer, L, paste0(lev, seq_along(L), "|"))
}
```

**Example 1** Using `dico` from the question

```
> str( indexer(dico) )
List of 3
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "1|1|1|1" "1|1|1|2" "1|1|1|3" "1|1|1|4"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "1|1|2|1" "1|1|2|2" "1|1|2|3" "1|1|2|4"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "1|2|1|1" "1|2|1|2" "1|2|1|3" "1|2|1|4"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "1|2|2|1" "1|2|2|2" "1|2|2|3" "1|2|2|4"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "1|3|1|1" "1|3|1|2" "1|3|1|3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "1|3|2|1" "1|3|2|2" "1|3|2|3" "1|3|2|4"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "2|1|1|1" "2|1|1|2" "2|1|1|3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "2|1|2|1" "2|1|2|2" "2|1|2|3"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "2|2|1|1" "2|2|1|2" "2|2|1|3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:4] "2|2|2|1" "2|2|2|2" "2|2|2|3" "2|2|2|4"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "2|3|1|1" "2|3|1|2" "2|3|1|3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "2|3|2|1" "2|3|2|2" "2|3|2|3"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "3|1|1|1" "3|1|1|2" "3|1|1|3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "3|1|2|1" "3|1|2|2" "3|1|2|3"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "3|2|1|1" "3|2|1|2" "3|2|1|3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "3|2|2|1" "3|2|2|2" "3|2|2|3"
  ..$ :List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "3|3|1|1" "3|3|1|2" "3|3|1|3"
  .. ..$ : chr [1:3] "3|3|2|1" "3|3|2|2" "3|3|2|3"
```

**Example 2** Here is an example of a list with a different depth and lack of balance:

```
L <- list(list(1:3, 5:7), 9:10)
```

giving:

```
> str( indexer(L) )
List of 2
 $ :List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "1|1|1" "1|1|2" "1|1|3"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "1|2|1" "1|2|2" "1|2|3"
 $ : chr [1:2] "2|1" "2|2"
```